# Apache's strange behaviour on /api request

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Requesting any resource of my site like /profile, /profile/, /market(with or without final slash) and /api/ goes fine but when I try to request /api(without final slash) I'm getting 301 Moved Permanently and redirecting to /api/?_url=api/api. Where the difference for Apache between /profile and /api and how to fix this redirection?

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpeg|jpg|svg)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller.php?_url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm using Apache 2.2.27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference is most likely that `/api/` is a directory and `mod_dir` is adding a trailing slash after above rule is run in `mod_rewrite` module. You can control this behavior by having code as this:

```
# turn off auto-trailing slash after a directory
DirectorySlash off
RewriteEngine on

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302,NE]    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpeg|jpg|svg)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller.php?_url=$1 [QSA,L]
```